# Typescript type safety in switch case statements

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm working with Redux and I'm trying to make my reducers type safe. I found some code example from the ngrx-store/example app where they perfectly succeed in doing this. (https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/actions/book.ts)

While integrating this in my own project, I noticed something strange, which I cannot explain. Check the following code sample (some comments inline):

```
// Action has a type and payload property
interface Action {
    type: string;
    payload?: any;
}

// Here I declare the action types as plain strings
const FIRST = "FIRST";
const SECOND = "SECOND";

// I create classes for every action with there respective types
class FirstAction implements Action {
    public type = FIRST;
    payload: { id: number };

    public constructor(id: number) {
        this.payload = { id };
    }
}

class SecondAction implements Action {
    public type = SECOND;

    public constructor() { }
}

// Create a union type
type Actions = FirstAction | SecondAction;

// Use the union type as type parameter in my function
function test(action: Actions): void {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FIRST:
                    // compiler will complain it cannot find the payload 
                    // property on Actions
            let temp = action.payload.id;
        case SECOND:
        // empty
        default:
        //empty
    }
}
```

If I replace the definition of the FIRST and SECOND properties into the following, it does work.

```
export function type<T>(label: T | ''): T {
    return <T>label;
}


const FIRST = type("FIRST");
const SECOND = type("SECOND");
```

As far as I can see, the type function only casts the string back to a string. Why does the code work with calling the `type` function but not when declaring the strings immediately?

Here's a [typescript playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%09type:%20string;%0D%0A%09payload?:%20any;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20type%3CT%3E(label:%20T%20%7C%20''):%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20%3CT%3Elabel;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20FIRST%20=%20type(%22FIRST%22);%0D%0Aconst%20SECOND%20=%20type(%22SECOND%22);%0D%0A%0D%0A//const%20FIRST%20=%20%22FIRST%22;%0D%0A//const%20SECOND%20=%20%22SECOND%22;%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FirstAction%20implements%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20type%20=%20FIRST;%0D%0A%09payload:%20%7B%20id:%20number%20%7D;%0D%0A%0D%0A%09public%20constructor(id:%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.payload%20=%20%7B%20id%20%7D;%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SecondAction%20implements%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20type%20=%20SECOND;%0D%0A%0D%0A%09public%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Actions%20=%20FirstAction%20%7C%20SecondAction;%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(action:%20Actions):%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%09switch%20(action.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09case%20FIRST:%0D%0A%09%09%09let%20temp%20=%20action.payload.id;%0D%0A%09%09case%20SECOND:%0D%0A%09%09//%20empty%0D%0A%09%09default:%0D%0A%09%09//empty%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) where you can just comment the definitons in or out (first with the working version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the TSC compiler cannot distinct the 2 values:

```
const FIRST = "FIRST";
const SECOND = "SECOND";
```

It's both of type `string`, thus TSC doesn't know which belongs to what. You have to give it a type, and that's what you're doing by casting it with your `type` function.

But it's easier if you write it as follows:

```
const FIRST: "FIRST" = "FIRST";
const SECOND: "SECOND" = "SECOND";
```

[Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%09type%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09payload%3F%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20type%3CT%3E(label%3A%20T%20%7C%20'')%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20%3CT%3Elabel%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Fconst%20FIRST%20%3D%20type(%22FIRST%22)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2Fconst%20SECOND%20%3D%20type(%22SECOND%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20FIRST%3A%20%22FIRST%22%20%3D%20%22FIRST%22%3B%0D%0Aconst%20SECOND%3A%20%22SECOND%22%20%3D%20%22SECOND%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FirstAction%20implements%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20type%20%3D%20FIRST%3B%0D%0A%09payload%3A%20%7B%20id%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09public%20constructor(id%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.payload%20%3D%20%7B%20id%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SecondAction%20implements%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20type%20%3D%20SECOND%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09public%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Actions%20%3D%20FirstAction%20%7C%20SecondAction%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(action%3A%20Actions)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%09switch%20(action.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09case%20FIRST%3A%0D%0A%09%09%09let%20temp%20%3D%20action.payload.id%3B%0D%0A%09%09case%20SECOND%3A%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20empty%0D%0A%09%09default%3A%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2Fempty%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: I was under the impression that if you called `type("FIRST")`, the T generic would be a string but apparently if will be "FIRST", correct? In the case I was describing, I expected the TSC to be smart enough to compare the string values to know what kind of action was handled in that part of the switch statement.

Comment: Yes, it'll be of type `FIRST` if you cast it like that. TSC can't know the value, it might be possible the values will change. Even though you declare it as a CONST, the values can change in your `Action` classes. Meaning you were comparing `string` against `FIRST`.

Answer (score 0):

It works just with const, not regular expressions, no variables.

```
switch(variable_expression) { 
   case constant1: { 
      //code; 
      break; 
   } 
   case constant2: { 
      //code; 
      break; 
   } 
   default: { 
      //code; 
      break; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I would use the `as` operator:

```
let temp = (action as FirstAction).payload.id;
```

Some other thoughts:
- Do you really need `Actions` if you already have `Action` that all
   your action classes implement?
- Extracting the reducer of each case into a function may help readability and unit testing.
- Remember that reducers take state and action, and return state (I understand you just simplified your example).

```
function test(state: State, action: Action): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FIRST:
            return handleFirst(state, action as FirstAction);
        case SECOND:
            return handleSecond(state, action as SecondAction);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

function handleFirst(state: State, action: FirstAction): State {
    let temp = action.payload.id;
    // ...
}

// ...
```

Comment: I don't really agree with this. In this case you are overriding the type checking of typescript by saying 'hey, this is a FirstAction'. It doesn't hold any value or type safety. You can just cast whatever value to a 'FirstAction'.