# Property does not exist on type inside switch

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do something like the following (albeit significantly more complicated):

```
interface Base {
    id: string;
    info: object;
}

interface A extends Base {
    example: boolean;
}

interface B extends Base {
    max: number;
}


interface ActionDataTypes {
    'for_a': A;
    'for_b': B;
}

function tryAction<A extends keyof ActionDataTypes>(id: string, action: A, data: ActionDataTypes[A]): boolean {

    switch(action){
        case 'for_a':
            //do stuff
            break;
        case 'for_b':
            //do stuff
            //this is a more complicated if statement
            if(data.max > 12){
                //do stuff
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

TypeScript gives the error `Property 'max' does not exist on type 'A | B'. Property 'max' does not exist on type 'A'.`

Any thoughts how how to fix it?

These questions did not resolve the issue:

- [Typescript type safety in switch case statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627277/typescript-type-safety-in-switch-case-statements)
- [Typescript does not consider the 'case' of a switch statement as a typeguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64493756/typescript-does-not-consider-the-case-of-a-switch-statement-as-a-typeguard)
- [Typescript is there a way to cast type for case in switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59616071/typescript-is-there-a-way-to-cast-type-for-case-in-switch)
- [TypeScript: Type guard does not work with switch statement when putting object into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403313/typescript-type-guard-does-not-work-with-switch-statement-when-putting-object-i)
- [Why Typescript throw error message: Property does not exist on type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860893/why-typescript-throw-error-message-property-does-not-exist-on-type)

Comment: please add `function` keyword to `tryAction`

Comment: Does [this appraoch](https://tsplay.dev/WzxXEN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not what am I missing?

Comment: No, since I have an additional parameter unrelated to the action type/data. I've updated the question.

Comment: Well, just put `id: string` before `...args: Args`. Would that work?

Comment: My bad... I had `...args: Args[]`. Yes it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the compiler is unable to type-narrow independent arguments, thus I suggest switching to a union of the args using the following [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
// [action: "for_a", data: A] | [action: "for_b", data: B]
type Args = {
  [K in keyof ActionDataTypes]: [action: K, data: ActionDataTypes[K]];
}[keyof ActionDataTypes];
```

And redefined the `tryAction` as follows:

```
function tryAction(id: string, ...args: Args) {}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnLAAmAXMhmFKAOYDc+hIMA9mcwEYBWECY9AvrlyhIsRCgCCyCAA9IIIhjSYcDWXAC2ABwA2EMu2bM9cEAKEjo8JGmlyICpeizI8BDXBlkQAVw3toc2FwK3FkCV5gZhAAETgwOAAVAE8tCCU3ZBYoAH04Mgl6Amyc9jJUILBUyShqJQBeVwYAbQBpRmQAawhk5hhwyOi4hJS0jABdMmbEMCiQMlaAGmQiePyB2aG10fS28fGBZu7e-ojN2O3qifpcGB8QQZBkSmSzuYAKYjIKKhBqZYAdEC4LUMAVQQBKJoEBDRCjIaaPZarBLjZCNEF1G4EDAAd2AYAQAAtkO8ZnMoZkYSpkAAiEpwWkkBgEAjsKAQOCdIqshA0+nMXLsJks1kAejFRGY5DAPhgMFFBGA-XeKLgAI8MmQAD5kABGABMlMV4sl0oocoVrNZgmtbI5XJ5gkEQA)